# schedule an API call inside unix/python environment

Tags: python, django, twitter, cron

I want to implement the schedule tweet feature as similar to hootsuite or buffer.

The way I have designed my current architecture is - a cron job runs every minute, which evokes a shell script, which fires a python/django command to see if there is any scheduled tweet in the database for current time. If yes, make an API call to twitter.

Is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

The same process can be scheduled with [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html)

Comment: Note that the celery solution also allows you to not have to check every minute.  You can simply schedule each tweet, and the task will run at roughly the scheduled time.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to define what's "better" way of doing it since it depends on implementation/problem.

For simple implementations I would go the same route you went, that is cron. If that's OK with you, i.e. there are no other problems you want to avoid I would advise sticking with it.

If you have need for something else you can for example:

- Start long running process/daemon which will track time and run/spawn actions on timer events
- Start long running process + task queue so that queue will send data to process when it should be run (Proposed by @Siva [django-celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) is such solution)
- Do a super-simple cron-independent solution which runs the tasks then sleeps for set amount of seconds (30s).